# Azure deploy repository from an organization

Tags: git, azure, github

I'm trying to deploy my Github project to Microsoft Azure. The repository is hosted in an organization account, and the user has read/write access to the repository.

But Azure says the user has no repositories.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify more information, are you talking about an Azure Web App and publish using Kudu i.e. "Connect to source control" in portal?

Exactly what error are you getting, are you sure its your orgs account that you authenticated when connected to github.

Can you clone the repository on your own machine or manually using the kudu console for your website?

Comment: I use the Azure portal, and add a new web app. I marked the 'publish from source' checkbox, and selected Github. The error I get is that I have no repositories in my Github account, though the organization does have one. @miracledev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Azure this is not possible. There is a [request feature](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6532040-allow-deployment-from-github-organization-reposito) dated 30/10/2014 but still no answer also [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/218) post tells that the API does not support this functionality (at least as of today) and it is intentionally not permitted. Go Azure Go!

Answer (score 3):

After granting access to use your account to azure (via azure api) you have to go into github and specify under user settings that azure should also be allowed to access your users organisation(s).
Once granted, the azure UI will update with an extra tab where you can specify the organisation. Once chosen, you can then choose that organisations repos.

Ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/using-app-service-web-apps-continuous-deployment-with-github-organizations/

This is not made clear through the Azure UI at all.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add Azure as a trusted third party to your organization